# JavaFX - Make TitledPane Sortable

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a plugin or something else to make a `TitledPane` sortable like this https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ or this [image] ?

Comment: Doesn't that just involve putting `TitledPane`s in a `VBox` (or `Accordion`) and registering the appropriate drag handlers on them? Have you tried to do that?

Comment: Yea, I went to try it by `setOnDrag...`, just wondering if there are already a plugin to do it, so I don't need to reinvent the wheel.